# How to apply a pandas function based on the value of another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns, one with some string values and another one with empty dicts:

```
ColA ColB
True  {}
False {}
True  {}
True  {}
False {}
False {}
True  {}
```

I have a function that updates a dict with some other values:

```
def update_dict(a):
    return a.update({"VAL":["yes"]})
```

How can I apply the above function to all the ColB cells that have "False" strings next to them in their ColA?:

```
ColA ColB
True  {}
False {"VAL":["yes"]}
True  {}
True  {}
False {"VAL":["yes"]}
False {"VAL":["yes"]}
True  {}
```

I know that in pandas you can use the apply function or applymap. However, I do not know how can I do it based on a previous column value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but working with `dict` in values of columns is not recommended, because lost all vectorized functions:

```
def update_dict(a):
    a.update({"VAL":["yes"]})
    return a

df['ColB'] = [update_dict(j) if i == 'False' else j for i, j in zip(df['ColA'], df['ColB'])]
print (df)
    ColA              ColB
0   True                {}
1  False  {'VAL': ['yes']}
2   True                {}
3   True                {}
4  False  {'VAL': ['yes']}
5  False  {'VAL': ['yes']}
6   True                {}
```

Comment: Thanks, but for this example where did you handle the "True/False" strings?

Comment: @J.Doe - It is `if i` what is same like `if i == True`

Comment: Its not a boolean, its a string. That's one of the problems I am having, Thanks!!

Comment: Then use `df['ColB'] = [j if i else {"VAL":["yes"]} for i, j in zip(df['ColA'].astype(bool), df['ColB'])]`

Comment: But still main question is - do you need dictionaries? There is some reson for it? Because working with them in pandas is pain, slow and problemtic.

Comment: Good to know thanks! I tried to `if i == "False"` however is adding the update to all the rows

Comment: Yes I need them... I know its a hassle but thats my format

Comment: @J.Doe - edited answer, also `update` working inplace so also changed function `update_dict`